# Ant Design Mobile Picker doesn't pop up from bottom when used in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, antd

I was testing the Picker component from Ant Design Mobile with React Native. But the Picker doesn't pop up from the bottom of the screen like it does in the demo (https://mobile.ant.design/components/picker/) when I pressed it.

I first defined an array of data:

```
const testData = [
    {value: 1, label: '1'},
    {value: 2, label: '2'},
    {value: 3, label: '3'},
];
```

Then I included the Picker component in the render method:

```
<Picker
    data={testData}
    values={[1]}
    cols={1}>
    <List.Item arrow="horizontal">Option</List.Item>
</Picker>
```

But when I pressed on the 'Option' field on screen, nothing happened. The picker didn't pop up.

Interestingly, though, when I put the DatePicker component in the render method simply like this:

```
<DatePicker>
    <List.Item>Pick a Date</List.Item>
</DatePicker>
```

The DatePicker did pop up when I pressed it.

So I don't know what I did wrong here. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you need to `triggerType="onClick"` prop to Picker component. And we've fixed it in the next release. The prop settings of the same component are a little different between Web and RN for now.